# Haml::Engine#render: "can't modify frozen NilClass (RuntimeError)"

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm working through the Haml section of the Pickaxe book (p. 281) with the code:

```
require 'haml'
engine = Haml::Engine.new(%{
%body
  #welcome-box
    %p= greeting
  %p
    As of
    = Time.now
    the reasons you gave were:
    %table
      %tr
        %th Reason
        %th Rank
      - for reason in reasons
        %tr
          %td= reason[:reason_name]
          %td= reason[:rank]
})

data = {
  greeting: 'Hello, Dave Thomas',
  reasons: [
    { reason_name: 'flexible',    rank: '87' },
    { reason_name: 'transparent', rank: '76' },
    { reason_name: 'fun',         rank: '94' },
  ]
}

puts engine.render(nil, data)
```

Running this yields the error:

```
/Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/engine.rb:136:in `block in render': can't modify frozen NilClass (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/engine.rb:135:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/engine.rb:135:in `ensure in render'
    from /Users/andrekibbe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/engine.rb:135:in `render'
    from haml_example.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

I'm confused about the Haml::Engine#render syntax, which according to the [documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html#render-instance_method) takes a block as its last of three arguments — while in the above code, the block is the first of two arguments. Why is the block supposed to be set to "nil"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `nil` as *scope* (first parameter of `Engine#render`)
`nil` is frozen in Ruby 2.2.

```
p nil.frozen? # Prints false in Ruby 2.0
p nil.frozen? # Prints true in Ruby 2.2
```

Frozen objects cannot be modified.  Thus, Ruby does not allow Haml to perform `instance_eval` on `nil` scope.  That's why we see the error.

Your code works fine in Ruby 2.0. My guess is that the example in the book was written before Ruby 2.2.

To fix your code, use below:

```
puts engine.render(Object.new, data)
```

PS:  The error is not related to the third parameter of `render`.  You can look at the [code of engine.rb](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.0.7/lib/haml/engine.rb) to confirm.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I assumed the first and second parameters were optional and being skipped. Interesting change in `nil` status. Thanks!